# finding and copying all files beginning with strings which are read from a text file

Tags: unix, while-loop

I have a text file from which I will read lines.
For each such line,  I want to find files beginning with that line in a specific folder and copy those files to the destination location

Suppose my text file, anmely `file.txt` reads like this:

```
abc
def
xyz
```

So, I want to find files beginning with `abc`, `def` and so on in the source folder and copy all those files in the destination folder.

I wrote the following command and its not working:

```
while read line
do
cp /srcdirectory/$line* /destdirectory/ < file.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
while read line
do 
    ls "$line"*    # replace me with cp 
done < file.txt  # then whole "while" statement executes reading from file.txt
```